# io connection event is not fired second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

With the help of **chokidar** module, I'm creating a folder watcher. My Server.js code is:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let path = require('path');
let chokidar = require('chokidar');
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

let port = process.env.port || 1337;

let clientPath = path.join(__dirname, 'client');

app.use(express.static(clientPath));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(clientPath, 'HTML1.html'));
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`listning on ${port}`);
});

let watcher = chokidar.watch(path.join(clientPath, 'images'),
    { ignored: /^\./, persistent: true }
);

watcher
    .on('add', function (path) {
        console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.emit('imageAddClient', { imagePath: path });
            socket.on('imageAddServer', function (data) {
                console.log(`${data.imagePath} has been processed at client`);
            });
        });
    })
    .on('change', function (path) {
        console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');
    })
    .on('unlink', function (path) {
        console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');
    })
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.error('Error happened', error);
    });
```

At client side, I've created angular factory to auto load page once an image is added. My client code is:

```
var app = angular.module('imageLoaderApp', []);
app.controller('loadController', function ($scope, socket) {
    try {
        images = [];
        socket.on('imageAddClient', function (data) {
            let fileName = data.imagePath.substring(data.imagePath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            console.log(fileName);
            images.push({ name: fileName, src: fileName });
            socket.emit('imageAddServer', { imagePath: fileName });
        });

        $scope.images = images;
        //console.log($scope.images);
    }
    catch (exception) {
        console.log(`Error from loadController ${exception}`);
    }
});

app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callBack) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                let args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callBack.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callBack) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data);
        }
    }
});
```

However, the 'connection' event from io is fired only **once** I start the server. Afterwords if I add an image file in the folder, I can see watcher event is fired but **'connection' event is not fired**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [Murf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850592/murf) put me on the right track. I just changed his sequence. I'm putting answer here just in case somebody needs it in future...
So the code for watcher and io goes like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    executeWatcher(socket);
    socket.on('imageAddServer', function (data) {
        console.log(`${data.imagePath} has been processed at client`);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });

});

let executeWatcher = function (socket) {
    watcher
        .on('add', function (path) {
            console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
            socket.emit('imageAddClient', { imagePath: path });
        })
        .on('change', function (path) {
            console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');
        })
        .on('unlink', function (path) {
            console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.error('Error happened', error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: @HermLuna, no. I usually write code in Typescript. I've written above code in JS after a long time. Any particular reason for asking?

Comment: No. I just see the template literals. So, if you are using babel. Take advantage of new features of es5 and es6. Great work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the io.on('connection') outside the watcher. You'll need to assign it on startup so it knows when a socket is connected.

```html
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 console.log('Socket connected!');

 socket.on('imageAddServer', function(data) {
  console.log('image has been processed at the client')
 });
 socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('Socket disconnected');
 });
});

watcher
    .on('add', function (path) {
        console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
  io.emit('imageAddClient', { imagePath: path }); //send it to the client sockets that are connected
    });
```

Use this code as a reference to update your code.

Comment: this way it is disconnecting the client every time page is loaded without creating a new connection or maintaining the connection.